# How to prevent mousedown event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mousedown

I have a sticky image slider which works with when the mouse button is clicked. I'm using mousedown event for the slider.

The slider is being triggered even if I click on other elements of the site.

```
this.listen("mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(this));
```

How can I prevent mousedown event if a menu button is clicked?

Comment: What happens in `this.listen`, are you using some known library?

Comment: I've changed  `this.listen` to:

`let mainEl = document.querySelector("main");
mainEl.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(this));`

and it worked